# How to download the second (or third) video using ytsearch on yt-dlp / youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl, yt-dlp

If I do

```
$ yt-dlp ytsearch:"some query"
```

yt-dlp downloads the first result of "some query" and everything is fine. What if I want to download the second result, how can I achieve that?

If it is not possible just using shell, how can I do it with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second result can be downloaded with `ytsearch2`. But the problem is that `ytsearch2` downloads two videos. But conveniently, youtube-dl (yt-dlp) has an option to get the nth video with `-I n`. So the command becomes

```
$ yt-dlp -I 2 ytsearch2:"some query"
```